# get month wise total, week wise total and day wise total in one mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to display month wise total, week wise total and then day wise total with days in one mysql query. I can do it using seperate queries but i want it in single query . Is it possible to display this hierarchy?

Comment: yes , I get it using seperate queries  e.g https://dyutiman.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/mysql-group-by-seven-days/ but want to merge those seperate queries in single .

Answer (score 1):

by using GROUP BY MONTH we found total by month and GROUP BY WEEK we found total by WEEK

```
Select sum(column) From table GROUP BY MONTH(column)
union
Select sum(column) From table GROUP BY WEEK(column)
```

and UNION operator combines the result

Answer (score 0):

This is from link you have provided.
use **UNION**:

```
SELECT  SUM(cost) AS total, MONTHNAME(date) AS month
FROM daily_expense 
GROUP BY month
UNION
SELECT  SUM(cost) AS total, CONCAT(date, ' - ', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week
FROM daily_expense
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
```